# using two json files and if conditions

Tags: javascript, json

I'm fetching data from two json files and the output depends on the json data stored in two different files:

```js
function fetchProjects(project) {
    fetch("/home.json", {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json"
            },
            cache: "no-cache",
            credentials: "same-origin",
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
                // hovered is the current element being hovered over
                let hovered = project.target.id;
                if (!hovered) {
                    fetch("/morework.json", {
                            headers: {
                                Accept: "application/json"
                            },
                            cache: "no-cache",
                            credentials: "same-origin",
                        })
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((data) => {
                            const [result] = data.filter((val) => val.images);
                        });
                }

                const [result] = data.filter((val) => val.uid.includes(hovered));
                console.log(result);
```

I'm looking for a way to get the `const result` and if `hovered` is empty it uses the values stored in `home.json`. But since I'm pretty new with using json and this `.then` method it seems like I can't close the `.then` method it without loosing the `const result`. So it will always fallback to the second `const result`...

Comment: Your code is really unclear. I strongly suggest rewriting it to  (a) use `async` / `await` instead of deeply nested `then` statements  and (b) **not** have multiple variables with the same name (`response`, `data`, `result`) and different contents

Comment: Would love to :) But I'm only starting to understand `.then`! will do that though

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" the result? Extract it where? Also, you have two instances of `result`, which one is it? And finally, what should be in `result` in both cases of `hovered`?

Comment: well, `result` should change depending if hovered is `project.target.id` or undefined. If its undefined, then it should fetch the `morework.json` file.
`console.log` is there to show me which `result`is passed by.

Comment: And what if it's defined? Is that when you fall back to the `home.json` file?

Comment: your code is missing all the closing braces at the end. Please use consistent indentation (you can use the snippet editor's "Tidy" button to neaten it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is declaring `result` to be global to the function, block level `const`s and `let`s are only available in said blocl.

I'd also recommend using [`async await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to avoid callback hell using chains of `.then()` calls like Quentin suggested.

```js
// custom fetch function for reuse
async function myFetch(path) {
    const response = await fetch(path, {
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    });
    return await response.json();
}

async function fetchProjects(project) {
    let result;
    if (!project.target.id) {
        const moreWorkData = await myFetch('/morework.json');
        [result] = moreWorkData.filter((val) => val.images);
    }
    else {
        const homeData = await myFetch('/home.json');
        [result] = homeData.filter((val) => val.uid.includes(hovered));
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Please note that I extracted the fetching logic outside as both fetches seems very similar.

Comment: thanks a lot,
actually, since `async`and `await` are quite new in my mind, I then have to execute the function, right?

Comment: Right, calling `fetchProjects(myProject)` would do the trick. You can also return the result from that function and call it using `await` as well.

Comment: alright, this is working wonderfully. I'm digging the await/async right now in order to properly understand what you did, thank you!